# AJAX form not working (malsup form plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to AJAX my contact form using JQuery Validation and Malsup's AJAX form plugin, but the form is not submitting at all (works without AJAX). I'm new to JS, so bear with me. Here's my script:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// attach handler to form's submit event 
$(".new-form").submit(function() { 
    // submit the form 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$(".new-form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        $(form).ajaxSubmit();
    },
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        message: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Please enter your name",
            minlength: "Your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please provide a valid email address"
        },
        message: {
            required: "Please provide a message"
        }

    }
});
});
</script>
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: do you get any message in the console ?

Comment: Is this actually valid? `$().ready(function() {` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should watch that example: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit

Add this code :

```
// attach handler to form's submit event 
$(".new-form").submit(function() { 
    // submit the form 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```